# How to properly manage errors and logs of a spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am testing Scrapy for the last couple of days and it is an amazing framework. One thing that I struggle with to fully understand is logging information after the spider is finished and managing logs.

I am logging the DUMP information to a file and some of it to the database.
[image]

However, I am not sure about what granularity of information should I be interested in? Say I am scraping a car website where is a page with links to cards and after clicking on a link I'll get a detail of the respective car. I am scraping on a daily basis.

What are the least information I should gather about that spider run? Is it all relevant HTTP error codes? Or how many items (cars) have been scraped and saved to my database? my goal is to have an overview over every spider's run and see if it was running successfully or if there were some errors (eg. the target website was down, or the website changed its structure, so the scraper could not scrape anything).

What information about the spider's run do you collect to know that everything's running smoothly? Sorry if the question is too broad, but I was not able to find anything relevant that would give me an idea about it.

Comment: Also consider https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/